# Bar chart with asterisks

Tags: java

The program is supposed to take in all five numbers from the user and then print all five sets of asterisks at the same time. I don't understand how to code it so that it prints the asterisks at the same time.

This is what my program is printing so far:

[image: This is what my program is printing so far]

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BarChart 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int i, j, n = 0; 

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a number between 1 and 30 ");
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {   
            n = input.nextInt();
            if (n > 30 || n < 1) {  
                System.out.println("Number out of limits, enter a number between 1 and 30 ");
                n = input.nextInt();
            }
            for (j = 0; j< n; j++)
                System.out.print("*");
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println(); 
    }
}
```

Also, I cannot use Array's as we haven't gone over that chapter yet.

This is what I have now and it's working.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BarChart 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n1 = 0;
        int n2 = 0;
        int n3 = 0;
        int n4 = 0;
        int n5 = 0;
        int i = 1;

        System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 30 ");
        n1 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 30 ");
        n2 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 30 ");
        n3 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 30 ");
        n4 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 30 ");
        n5 = input.nextInt();

        for(i = 1; i <= n1; i++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();

        for(i = 1; i <= n2; i++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();

        for(i = 1; i <= n3; i++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();

        for(i = 1; i <= n4; i++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();

        for(i = 1; i <= n5; i++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println(); 

        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you cannot use arrays then use five different variables and then call printing method five times passing the appropriate variable.  Ugly but makes you appreciate the power of collections.

Comment: Could I use a switch statement?

Comment: What for? You need to print all at the same time, right?

Comment: Are the bars supposed to be vertical or horizontal?

Comment: You need to go up in the lines, not all consoles support this. How do you run the program?

Comment: My teacher wants the results printed horizontally. I'm using Eclipse. The program is working like this. I'm eager to learn array's as this seems over complicated.

Comment: I'm just new and don't really know what I'm doing, trying to stay calm and learn. Youtube videos have been helping me more than the textbook. The textbook does a bad job of explaining things to me and I'm more of a visual learner. I appreciate all of the help.